# Matomo UserID specific report

Tags: matomo

I am using Matomo UserID to track users - https://matomo.org/docs/user-id/#user-id-report

What I am not able to figure out is how I can view the Report of that actual user via the UserID - I know I can view the report of the user via their visitorID with a link like

https://host.com/index.php?date=today&module=Widgetize&action=iframe&visitorId=12341234&showMap=0&idSite=1&period=day&moduleToWidgetize=Live&actionToWidgetize=getVisitorProfilePopup

but I would like to view the report of the user via the UserID.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help for the developers I figured it out:

https://host.com/index.php?date=today&module=Widgetize&action=iframe&idSite=1&period=day&segment=userId%3D%3D12341234&moduleToWidgetize=Live&actionToWidgetize=getVisitorProfilePopup